# Enforce <strong> tag against css style

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this css style in page:

```
*{
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I also have a div with an id `sample` and a `<strong>` tag as its children. See code below:

```
<div id="sample">
    <strong>
        Strong tag must be enforce.
    </strong>
<div>
```

How will I enforce the tag `strong` against the css style above?

Comment: Why do you have such CSS rule for every element?

Comment: @Vohuman -> It was the default css of the page. Im just overriding it.

Comment: So it seems you have a long way to go. That makes the styling and maintaining it very _difficult_ and _time-consuming_.

Answer (score 1):

Add css style for `strong`

```css
*{
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

strong { 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">
    <strong>
        Strong tag must be enforce.
    </strong>
<div>
```

Or you can do it by applying inline css style:

```css
*{
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">
    <strong style="font-weight:bold">
        Strong tag must be enforce.
    </strong>
<div>
```

Comment: Is there another way I could use , without adding css code. I just wanna do it within the tag. Is that possible?

Comment: That rule doesn't change the weight of the fonts. That doesn't "enforce the tag strong against the css style".

Comment: @Aliyah You can also do inline css style `<strong style="font-weight:bold"></strong>`

Comment: @Vohuman: It does - it sets the weight to normal. See Fe-fi-fo-fum's answer.

Comment: @Aliyah Does this answer your question? Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional note:

The `font` shorthand is going to set the optional properties of the shorthand to the `initial` value, even if they are not specified explicitly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font

The initial value of `font-weight` is `normal`.

In your case, the asterisk `(*)` selects *every* element, and applies `font-weight: normal` to them.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 forms:

```css
*{font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}

#sample strong{
  font-weight:bold
}


#sample2 b{
  font-weight:bold
}

/**or u can**/

b,
strong{
  font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<div id="sample">
    <strong>
        Strong tag must be enforce.
    </strong>
<div>
  
  
 <hr>
  
  <div id="sample2">
    <b>
        Strong tag must be enforce.
    </b>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*:not(#sample) {
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```